# Sencha Touch 2 nested models and data stores

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-2

I hardly even know how to ask this one, but here goes.

I have two models, a Platter which contains many Recipes:

```
Ext.define('NC.model.Platter', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  config: {
    fields: [
      { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
      { name: 'text', type: 'string' }
    ],
    associations: [
      {type: 'hasMany', model: 'NC.model.Recipe', name: 'recipes', filterProperty: 'text'}
    ]
  }
});

Ext.define('NC.model.Recipe', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
  config: {
      fields: [
        { name: 'name', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'image', type: 'string' },
        { name: 'stepsText', type: 'string', mapping: 'properties.preparationText' },
        { name: 'ingredientsText', type: 'string', mapping: 'properties.ingredientsText' }
      ]
    }
});
```

Platters are basically different filters on an online recipe store. So I might have a thousand recipes but my 'Pizza' platter will only return pizza recipes (thus the filterProperty). Platters are just created and stored locally, whereas Recipes are online. So, the stores:

```
Ext.define('NC.store.Platters', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

  config: {
    model: 'NC.model.Platter',
    storeId: 'Platters',
    proxy: {
      type: 'localstorage',
      id: 'platters'
    },
    data : [
        {name: 'Noodles', text: 'noodle'},
        {name: 'Baked', text: 'bake'},
        {name: 'Pizza', text: 'pizza'}
    ]
  }
});

Ext.define('NC.store.Recipes', {
  extend: 'Ext.data.Store',

  config: {
    model: 'NC.model.Recipe',
    storeId: 'Recipes',
    proxy: {
      type: 'jsonp',
      url: 'xxxx',  // url here (redacted)
      callbackKey: 'callback',
      filterParam: 'text',
      extraParams: {
        // credentials and tokens here (redacted)
      },
      reader: {
        type: 'json',
        idProperty: 'uuid',
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Now, I would like to create a dataview of dataviews. A list of Platters, each containing it's list of Recipes:

```
Ext.define('NC.view.DiscoverGrid', {
  extend: 'Ext.DataView',
  xtype: 'discovergrid',
  id: 'discover',

config: {
    title: 'Discover',
    baseCls: '',
    useComponents: true,
    defaultType: 'platter',
    store: 'Platters',
    ui: 'light'
  }
});

Ext.define('NC.view.Platter', {
  extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
    xtype: 'platter',

  config: {
      layout: 'fit',
      height: '100px',
      list: {
        itemTpl: '{name}',
        inline: true,
        scrollable: {
          direction: 'horizontal',
          directionLock: true
        }
      },
      dataMap: {
        getList: {
          setData: 'recipes'
        }
      }
    },

    applyList: function(config) {
      return Ext.factory(config, Ext.DataView, this.getList());
    },

  updateList: function(newList, oldList) {
    if (newList) {
        this.add(newList);
      }

  if (oldList) {
        this.remove(oldList);
      }
    }
  });
```

Now, how do I populate the platter's recipes? If I populate the Platters with a little in-line recipe data like, so:

```
data : [
    {name: 'Noodles', text: 'noodle', recipes: [
      { name: 'Pasta', ingredientsText: "Tomatoes\nPassata\n1tsp Oregano", preparationText: "Do something\nAdd passata\nmix in oregano and tomato",
        ingredients: [{ text: "bla"}]
      }
    ]},
    {name: 'Baked', text: 'bake'},
    {name: 'Pizza', text: 'pizza'}
]
```

... it works straight out and renders the dataview with Pasta in it. So I just need to know how to get my platters to fill their recipe data. Where (I assume in a controller on an initialize event of some sort) and how do I wire this up? And am I using the filterProperty correctly? I don't completely understand the docs on this, but I think it generally filters on a foreign key, which I don't have, and that the filterProperty overrides this. So that the URL will have &text=noodle appended to it.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This certainly doesn't seem to be utilising the association and store structure that I think Sencha Touch has, but even after progressing to the point of getting the `recipes()` association to load properly, I couldn't ever get this to trigger the dataview to refresh. I was spending too much time on it, so I went with a less elegant solution. I pass the filter text to a setter on the Platter which sets it's store with this filter in the param. It works at least!

```
Ext.define('NC.view.PlatterDataItem', {
  extend: 'Ext.dataview.component.DataItem',
  xtype: 'platterdataitem',


  config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    height: '130px',
    cls: 'platter',
    list: {
    },
    dataMap: {
      getList: {
        setRecipeFilters: 'text'
      }
    }
  },

  applyList: function(config) {
    return Ext.factory(config, NC.view.Platter, this.getList());
  },

  updateList: function(newList, oldList) {
    if (newList) {
      this.add(newList);
    }


    if (oldList) {
      this.remove(oldList);
    }
  }
});

Ext.define('NC.view.Platter', {
  extend: 'Ext.DataView',
  xtype: 'platter',


  config: {
    layout: 'vbox',
    height: '130px',
    itemCls: 'platter-item',
    itemTpl:  '<div class="thumb"><tpl if="image != null"><img src="{image}" /></tpl></div>'+
              '<div class="name">{name}</div>',
    inline: {
      wrap: false
    },
    scrollable: {
      direction: 'horizontal',
      directionLock: true
    }
  },

  setRecipeFilters: function(text) {
    var store = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
      model: 'NC.model.Recipe',
      autoLoad: true,
      proxy: {
        type: 'jsonp',
        url: 'xxxxx',
        callbackKey: 'callback',
        extraParams: {
          // credentials & text filter param
        },
        reader: {
          type: 'json',
          idProperty: 'uuid',
        }
      }
    });

    this.setStore(store);
  }
});
```